# magento2: How to get address' region while checkout selecting address

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods, shipping-address

```
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
    $destCountryId = $request->getDestCountryId();
    $destState = $request->getDestRegionCode();
    $destCity = $request->getDestCity();
```

use this code I can get the address in my custom shipping method.
but if people select address no entered into input,sometime I can't get RegionCode,getDestRegionCode() return null.

After observation, I found if State/Province is entered into input not select from Magento after checkout the address will be saved.Next time to select this address in Shipping Address page, getDestRegionCode() return null.

What's wrong with my code? How to get State/Province reliably?
[image]

In this way getDestRegionCode() return null not 'zhejiang '

[image]

In this way entered zhejiagn getDestRegionCode() can get right value 'zhejiang'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly I Find no way to get region If region is entered not select from form when customer checkout select address.

But We can use di.xml to rewrite

> Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address

```
public function getRegionCode()
{
    $regionId = $this->getData('region_id');
    $region = $this->getData('region');

    if (!$regionId && is_numeric($region)) {
        if ($this->getRegionModel($region)->getCountryId() == $this->getCountryId()) {
            $this->setData('region_code', $this->getRegionModel($region)->getCode());
        }
    } elseif ($regionId) {
        if ($this->getRegionModel($regionId)->getCountryId() == $this->getCountryId()) {
            $this->setData('region_code', $this->getRegionModel($regionId)->getCode());
        }
    } elseif (is_string($region)) {
        $this->setData('region_code', $region);
    } elseif (is_array($region)) {
        $this->setData('region_code', $region['region']);
    }
    return $this->getData('region_code');
}
```

Fist you need to noee which data is you need , then do like this code.

```
elseif (is_array($region)) {
        $this->setData('region_code', $region['region']);
    }
```

Then, we can use

```
$request->getDestRegionCode();
```

to get value.

Answer (score 1):

`Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest` is work fine when we calculating shipping method.

### Understand how the Shipping address is saved & shipping methods are calculated at checkout.

At checkout steps, when **a user enters shipping country Or Shipping region or Selecting an existing**  then **an ajax request happen** which is **take address fields data** from **Shipping Address form** and set address data to `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest` object and which used all shipping methods for **calculating the shipping cost and it's availability** . But request **does not save** the address to the Database table **quote_addrss**.

So, in that request, if you use `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest` then you will get right `$request->getDestCountryId()`  etc.

But Shipping Address is saved when we select a shipping method at the checkout by click on **`Next`** button. that time's ***ajax does not request shipping cost calculation method***, So if use `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest` on that time , **on your code that does not give right address details**.

`Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest` is only working fine when you shipping method is calculated.

### Update

use **`$request->getDestRegionCode()`**  getting Region field data. Take look on method `\Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress::getRegionCode()`

Comment: Sorry, may be you can't understand my problem .I need getDestRegionCode() 同get region for calculated shipping method .
When I choose address not input address, getDestRegionCode() return null.

Comment: I use this function for calulate shipping method in my shipping carrier model collectRates()

Comment: then check ajax request which estimating the shipping method list on your browser. i Check  address field values are passing properly or not.

Comment: magento.com/default/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods-by-address-id
select address ajax send request to this url ,param is entity_id in table customer_address_entity.
use entity_id can find address and region has right value but region_id is 0.

In this mode of operation getDestRegionCode() return null.

Comment: Is Region field are dropdown  field or input type field?

Comment: dropdown can get right value , input type return null.

Comment: use $request->getDestRegionCode()

Comment: yes ,i use  $request->getDestRegionCode(),but if region field was input type field before select address in this time,this time  $request->getDestRegionCode() return null.

Comment: You have to use `$request->getDestCountryId()` when  region field is select . use `$request->getDestRegionCode()` when use region field is input.

Comment: sorry . i can't understand.  I need region everytime. There's no way to get region when region field is input?

Comment: There are two fields for saving first one region_id which save state id if the state is a drop field. And if the state is input then it will save to a field name `region` field.You must have take a look `\Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress::getRegionCod` and you understand